# Remove text and link from e-mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I have auto generated receipts coming to my e-mail (Outlook) that I have built rules to forward to different CSR's based text in the body of the e-mail.

There is an "unsubscribe" option and occasionally either our CSR's or their clients are clicking on which removes me from getting these e-mails.

is there a way removing this string of text along with the link?

The string is as follows:

If you no longer wish to receive emails from Self Service Terminal, please click on the 'Unsubscribe' link below: 
Unsubscribe

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [Finding and Replacing Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211953(v=office.11).aspx) also please see
[Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help:

```
    With Selection.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = "If you no longer wish to receive emails from Self Service Terminal, please click on the 'Unsubscribe' link below: Unsubscribe"
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
      Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
```

See Om3rs link in the comment for more information on this.